# Why isn't free dyno usage updating?

Tags: heroku

I've had this heroku account for almost two weeks, but in the billing section my free dyno hours used this month remains at 0%. This isn't possible because I've set an uptimerobot to hit my heroku API every 29 minutes (to prevent it from sleeping).

Contemplating upgrading to Hobby so accurate info is nice to have here.